# Linking to external functions in dynamic libraries with LLVM

Tags: llvm, dynamic-linking, extern, ffi, llvmlite

In my project, I am emitting LLVM IR which makes calls to external functions in dynamic libraries.

I declare my external functions like:

```
declare %"my_type"* @"my_function"()
```

In the external library, functions are declared like:

```
extern "C" {
    my_type* my_function();
}
```

When I compile the IR and run it, the process immediately crashes. The same behavior happens if I declare and call a nonsense function that I know doesn't exist, so I assume what's happening is that the external function is not being found/linked. (I don't think that the function itself is crashing).

I am using Python's `llvmlite` library for this task, and within the same process where I JIT and invoke my LLVM IR, I have another python library imported which requires the external dynamic library; so I assume that library is loaded and in-memory.

The procedure I'm using to compile and execute my LLVM code is basically the same as what's in [this document](https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/binding/examples.html), except that the IR declares and invokes an external function. I have tried invoking `cos()`, as in [the Kaleidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html), and this succeeds, so I am not sure what is different about my own library functions.

I have tried adding an underscore to the beginning of the function name, but I get the same result. (Do I need to add the underscore in the LLVM function declaration?)

- How do I verify my assumption that the process is crashing because the named function isn't found?
- How do I diagnose why the function isn't being found?
- What do I need to do in order to make use of external functions in a dynamic library, from LLVM code?

---

Edit: It seems there is indeed trouble getting the function pointers to my external function. If I try to merely print the function address by replacing my calls with `%"foo" = ptrtoint %"my_type"* ()* @"my_function" to i64` and return/print the result, it still segfaults. Merely trying to obtain the pointer is enough to cause a crash! Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Edit: Also forgot to mention— this is on Ubuntu (in a Docker container, on OSX).

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out— I was missing that I need to call `llvmlite.binding.load_library_permanently(filename)` in order for the external symbols to become available. Even though the library is already in memory, the function still needs to be invoked. (This corresponds to the LLVM native function `llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::LoadLibraryPermanently()`).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413217/how-to-resolve-current-process-symbols-in-llvm-mcjit-based-jit), it appears calling the above function with `nullptr` will import all the symbols available to the process.

Oddly, on OSX, I found that the external symbols were available even though `load_library_permanently()` had not been explicitly called— I'm not sure why this is (perhaps the OSX build of `llvmlite` itself happened to call the function with `nullptr`, as above?).